# Add restart button when game is over

Tags: java, swing, button

I am a beginner in Java.Swing and have tried making my own Snake Game based on an example I found on the internet, and hence learn through this process. It went all good, game works, but now I am trying to add a restart button at the "game over" screen. The program is structured as following:

Main program

```
public Snake() {
    add(new Board());
    setResizable(false);
    pack();
    setTitle("Snake");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame ex = new Snake();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

Board: (trying to only paste the relevant code)

```
Board() {
    initializeVariables();
    addKeyListener(new EventHandler()); 
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setFocusable(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT));
    loadImages();

    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();
}
```

with override on the following methods:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ///
    repaint();
}
```

When the game is over, the snake isn't drawn anymore, but the following method is called inside paintComponent/doDrawing:

```
private void gameOver(Graphics g) {
    String msg = "Game Over";
    String msg2 = "New Game?";
    Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, DOT_SIZE);
    FontMetrics metr = getFontMetrics(small);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(small);
    g.drawString(msg, (BOARD_WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, BOARD_HEIGHT / 2);

    g.drawString(msg2, (BOARD_WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, (BOARD_HEIGHT / 2) + DOT_SIZE*2);}
```

Really, what I need is that the second string "New Game?" be responsive and restart the game. How would I do that?

Of course, I thought about using a JButton. However, I am still unsure about how JFrame and JPanel work. I tried creating the button in actionPerformed(), only when the game is over, and use add() to add it to the screen. It does not show, and I believe the reason is that the JPanel is already taking the entire screen (JFrame?) and so the Button would need to be drawn after it but that would be outside of the JFrame.

May I have any advice on how to proceed further?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try adding the button to the JPanel instead of the JFrame. I think that should make it visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by adding the button when Board() is called but setting it to "invisible" and only showing it (and enabling it) when game is over. The method:

```
private void addRestartButton() {
    String buttonText = "New Game?";
    restartButton = new JButton(buttonText);
    Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, size);
    restartButton.setFont(font);

    setLayout(null);
    restartButton.setBounds(x,y,w,z);
    add(restartButton);

    restartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            restart();
        }
    });  

    setButtonVisibility(false);
}
```

I do not know exactly why the button was not showing up in the first place; maybe  it could not be added at a later stage in the program? or perhaps the visibility was set to false by default. Since I just tried doing it this way and it worked, I did not go back to see why. Anyway, here are some of my findings:

- the repaint() method is called even when the timer is stopped
- i had to first use setLayout(null) to allow me to reposition the button
- the button needs its own actionListener (which seems obvious now)

I believe the next step is to restructure the whole game by making a separate JPanel for each screen (so start page, game, endgame) and handling the panel changes in the main Snake() program.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
   dispose();  

   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame ex = new Snake();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

i dont know is only a supposition i would try it on the core of the replay method

more code is the welcome in order to help you